# how to get data from database in the basis of gridview index?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view. When I bind the grid view data from database, all data has to be bound at the time. It is affected to the performance of my application. I am always used index on grid view. So I want that when I clicking each index of grid view, the particular count of data has to return from database. Can any one help for this issue?

Comment: Can you share some code, that will give us some idea what you have already done.

Answer (score 0):

What i got from question is that right now you are pulling all the data from a table and binding with the gridview, which of-course is not good and you want to pull only the required amount of data depending on the current page number. Please see the following article for the solution.

[ASP.Net Grid View Custom Paging](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-paging-with-gridview-control-in-Asp-Net-4-5/)